# How do you send payload data with initial request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Lets say, for example, we have a page that has a table with list of users. I could render the HTML with the table of users, but that isn't very friendly with Angular. I can also AJAX back to the server for the data, but then I have to wait for the initial page to render and make an additional HTTP request, which adds additional delay.

Is there a way to send my payload data along with my initial request so I don't have to AJAX for the data and I can still use angular binding (e.g. ng-repeat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to access server data without executing Javascript is to have the server include that data in the initial request for the web page.  This would require using a server side language such as PHP, Ruby, or ASP.NET that can query the data, add it to your web page, and send the updated web page in it's inital http resonse.

However, this concept completely undermines the purpose of using a client side framework such as AngularJS.  Angular wants to be in charge of your data access, and I would recommend letting it be.  Angular doesn't know about Data that it didn't retrieve, so you are going to have to also dynamically modify your page scripts to tell Angular about the data that the server retrieved.  This is all going down a dark road that you do not want to go down. you will simply be doing double work.

If your concern is that your users will be see a brief delay between the page load and the initial data loading, you even have the option to keep the screen blank until the initial data loads using things directives like ng-cloak and ng-bind.  If you are concerned about the delays in retrieving data after the initial page load, remember that a full-page HTTP request and full page reload takes much longer than an ajax call that only updates a single part of your page.

If you don't want to be using Ajax calls, you don't want to be using AngularJS.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explanation helped me to understand more than disliking of question :)

Comment: Ok, but what about SEO? If I am using angularjs for get for example users list, search bot will see only angular placeholders instead of users list because it can't run scripts. But if I load users list using PHP, search bot will take users list without problem.

Comment: SEO with AJAX Applications is a tricky monster.  If SEO is important, and you want the speed of an AJAX framework like AngularJS, you will definitely want to read about Website stapshots, as detailed in Googles instructions here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/ 

It is very possible, but it is definitely a point to consider when building a Single Page application.  If you want to see a Demo, look no further than google's own Angularjs API page.  Just google "NG-hide" and look for a result from docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com.  That site is an Angularjs site.‎